# Installing/Updating Root Certificates in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, amazon-ses

First of all, I'm not a Sysadmin, I'm a developer. My Problem is now that the Application I develop is installed and runs on an Windows Server 2003 at a client.

I'm using AWS SES Service to send e-Mails to Members or Customers. Since the SSL Certs of this Server is out of date, the connection can not be established.

My question is now: 
How can I update (at best all) Root CAs in Windows Server 2003 so the SES Service will work?

Comment: unfortunately, as Windows 2003 is EOL since July 2015 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-2003), questions about it are not really suited for SF. I am not sure whether they would be considered on-topic elsewhere (maybe SuperUser's rules would allow it - you may want to check their help center).

Answer (score 2):

To do this manually, download the file http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab (updated twice a month).

Using any archive program (i.e. 7-Zip, or Windows Explorer) unpack authrootstl.cab to get the authroot.stl file from within.

Right click on the authroot.stl file in windows explorer and click on "Install CTL" from the explorer menu.

Click Next -> Next -> Finish

Re-check your certificates and they should all be updated!

This is even more important now that the certificate rules are changing.